# Where/what is the 'location bar' in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome as my default browser but a recent inadvertent action resulted in New Tab appearing with it & then displacing it immediately.  I found some instructions for getting rid of it but the first step is to type in 'the location bar' the words 'about:config'.

My problem, as always, is the first step:  where/what is the 'location bar' ?

Answer (score 2):

Location bar is where you see the address of the website. Right now it should have "superuser.com" in it.

Answer (score 1):

type `Alt+D` and you'll have the cursor right into it.

it's the bar in which you type URLs.